# Method to find if a snake in a snake game has made a loop

Tags: java, game-development

I am relatively new to java, and I have an idea for a mechanic I want to implement in to my game. However, I have no idea how to go about solving this problem. My snake game works on a basic coordinate system. I want it to be so that when the snake makes a closed loop (a rectangle or square) the game will detect it has made a loop. I have tried writing a method to locate the part of the snake's body that is the most upper-left, and then checking from there, but it seems to not work very well. Here is the method I attempted to write, if It helps at all. Thank you for any help!!

````
public boolean checkRing()
    {
        
        int topLeftX = 5000;
        int topLeftY = 5000;
        for(int i = bodyParts;i>0;i--) 
        {
            // Finds coordinates of top left box
            
            if(x[i] < topLeftX) 
            {
                topLeftX = x[i];
            }
            if(y[i] < topLeftY)
            {
                topLeftY = y[i];
            }
        }
        
        // Use isBody() method below (not bug tested) to check for rectangle
        boolean lineFoundVert = false;
        int checkingX = topLeftX;
        int checkingY = topLeftY;
        int vertCounter = 1;
        while(!lineFoundVert)
        {
            if(isBody(checkingX, checkingY))
            {
                vertCounter++;
                checkingX++;
            }
            else
                lineFoundVert = true;
        }
        
        boolean lineFoundHori = false;
        checkingX = topLeftX;
        checkingY = topLeftY;
        int horiCounter = 1;
        while(!lineFoundHori)
        {
            if(isBody(checkingX, checkingY))
            {
                horiCounter++;
                checkingY++;
            }
            else
                lineFoundHori = true;
        }
        
        debug1X = topLeftX + 1;
        debug1Y = topLeftY + vertCounter;
        debug2X = topLeftX + horiCounter;
        debug2Y = topLeftY + 1;
        if(isBody(topLeftX + 1, topLeftY + vertCounter) && isBody(topLeftX + horiCounter, topLeftY + 1))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }```
````

Comment: What r u trying to achieve? If u just need to know whether the snake hit itself it is easiest to check at every turn if any of the body parts has the same coordinate as one of the others

Comment: I already have collision code and all of that. It works as a playable snake game. I want the method to be able to locate rectangles or squares made by the snake.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approximate solution:

```
private boolean isEdgeCoordinate(Coordinate[] bodyparts, int index) {
   // for every bodypart check that its neighbours (bodypart one before and 
   //  bodypart one after) dont share X axis and dont share Y axis. As long 
   // as that is the case it is an edge.

   //additionally for the last bodypart you needto check that it has first 
   // bodypart as a neighbour and check them as neighbours otherwise no 
   // rectangle to begin with
}
```

using this method check the amount of edges in your bodyparts array. If the total number of edges == 4 you have got a square/rectangle

Comment: Neighbours always share either X or Y coordinate. Which one they share defines the direction. Edges may be detected by a changing direction. Important: There might be an edge between head and tail. So the edge detection must run from head to head, not from head to tail.

Comment: i mean that one neighbour doesnt share the x y with the other neighbour - meaning bodypart[i-1]doesnt share x and y with bodypart[i+1]